# Will Windows Dlls work on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows, dll, windows-phone-7

I am developing a relatively simple .NET class library mainly using basic value and reference types. To save code duplication, I would like to export to 1 DLL which could be used by both Windows PCs and Windows Phone devices? Is this possible? As far as I know, all methods are compatible with the .NET and Compact .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as you stick to the Compact Framework subset, it will work. Check out this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163387.aspx) on that same topic.

Quote:

> The techniques and principles
>   discussed in this article can be
>   utilized when writing cross-device
>   code—applications that target Windows
>   devices with differing form factors
>   (different screen sizes, orientations,
>   touch screens and so on).